# Showing divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}}$$

As $n \to \infty$, we see that $n \ln n \gg (\ln n)^{3/2}$. Hence

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}} \sim^{\infty} \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln n}, 0 \leq a_n$$ By the integral test, the last sum is diverging making the original sum divergent. Is this correct?

Comment: For $n = 1$ the denominator is $0$. Start the sums at $n = 2$. Apart from that, yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: I think I'd prefer $\sim_\infty$ to be more precise if I was reading it. Maybe it's common though and I just haven't come across it.

Comment: When you are using $a_n\sim b_n$ you need also $a_n\ge 0$ to conclude $\sum a_n\sim\sum b_n$. This is obvious in this case, but it needs to be written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes your argument is correct by [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) indeed

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}}}{\frac{1}{n\ln n}}=\frac{n\ln n}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}}\to 1$$

and  $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ diverges (also by condensation test).

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct. For sufficiently large $n$, we have $n\geq(\ln n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$,
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
2n\ln n & = & n\ln n+n\ln n\\
 & \geq & n\ln n+(\ln n)^{\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{n\ln n+(\ln n)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\geq\frac{1}{2n\ln n}.
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n\ln n}=+\infty
$$
by integral test, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n+(\ln n)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=+\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Quite short with *asymptotic analysis*:

It is well-known from high-school (albeit with other notations) that $\sqrt{\ln^3 n}=o(n)$, hence ${}=o(n\ln n)$, so that
$$\frac{1}{n\ln n + \sqrt{\ln^3n}}\sim_\infty \frac1{n\ln n},$$
and the latter is known to be a divergent *Bertrand's series* by the integral test.